# Oracle.DataAccess: call stored procedure with custom type

Tags: .net, oracle, stored-procedures

Suddenly have difficulties with getting data from third-party oracle stored procedure from .NET application.

Here is the procedure header:

```
PROCEDURE myProc(in_n IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                 in_wid IN VARCHAR2, 
                 out_Status OUT TMP_RetVal)
```

where

```
TYPE TMP_RetVal IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

I tried several diffrent DbTypes, i.e.:

```
public static void Execute(int id, string whId)
{
     using (var connection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["oracleConn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("DBO.myPack.myProc", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("in_n", id);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("in_wid", whId,);
            var res = new OracleParameter("out_Status", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
            res.Size = 1;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(res);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

}
```

What should be proper DbTypes for both input and output parameters for this particular case?

Best regards and big thanks for help

Comment: Please elaborate on _"Suddenly have difficulties"_

Comment: Nevermind, just got how to fix it ) 
res.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;